# Best resources to learn suitecrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am a newbie to CRM although worked in laravel, WordPress.
I've to extend a built-in project of suitecrm i go through with developer guide but when I have to dig in realtime implementation of builtin project I am stuck.
Your guidance will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

SuiteCRM was based on SugarCRM 6.5, so you can take a look to the old documentation.

https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Unsupported_Versions/Sugar_6.5/index.html

Also, there is a book https://issuu.com/dunca/docs/the_definitive_guide_to_sugarcrm

Current SuiteCRM has of course evolved but the core concepts are the same.

Next, you can use current SuiteCRM docs https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/

A note on developing on SuiteCRM.

Having worked with small medium and large implementations since the SugarCRM era, I have to say that if you know Laravel, please don't expect a serious platform, SuiteCRM is just a collage of PHP files with some kind of coherence, not SuiteCRM's fault, just a very poor design from sugar since the beginning.

You will have to get used to digging into the code, forum, and GitHub to find out why things don't work, and community support from salesAgility is very poor ,but they are improving and have a roadmap for a 8 version wich makes great changes.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your response I am putting my efforts to learn the how suitecrm works but as compared to laravel suitecrm is not getting easy to understand

Comment: Not at all, laravel is the nicest/easiest most completed framework to work with, SuiteCRM is the exact opposite, be patient and good luck and keep asking